# RegExp incorrectly matches backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a string for only alphanumeric characters and whitespaces.

For some reason though the expression also matches strings with backslashes:

```
var expression = new RegExp("^[A-z0-9 ]+$");
console.log(expression.test("Hello World")); // True
console.log(expression.test("Hello\\ World")); // True.... WHY?
```

Why is the backslash matching this expression? How can I make it so it doesn't?

Comment: Classes are a tenant of regular expressions. For simple stuff like this, always suspect a typo... unless you have no idea about what a range operator is inside a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var expression = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/;
```

The `A-z` matches more than just letters: `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_` and `` ` ``.

[image]

```js
var expression = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/;
console.log(expression.test("Hello World"));   // => True
console.log(expression.test("Hello\\ World")); // => False
```

Comment: We should run an initiative to DDOS all tutorial websites that promote the use of `[A-z]`. Seriously.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: It's unfortunately the correct way to specify all alphabets in a language in POSIX regex, when we set collation for a particular language.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Could you please provide some reference, or an example?

Comment: `[[ "ABCEDEF[]_abcdef" =~ ([A-z]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` on Cygwin with `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` gives `ABCEDF`. If you set `LC_COLLATE` to `C` (on Cygwin, done with `export`), it will give the expected `ABCEDEF[]_abcdef`